# Unable to set OAuthconnection seting

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I create a microsoft teams app using App studio and added a bot to it. I am using the sample code provided for the bot here https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/python/46.teams-auth. However the sample required a ConnectionName setting in config.py. But I do not see a OAuthsetting section in the created bot. How can this config be set.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the authentication setting in Azure portal Bot Channels Registration.

Setting -> Add Setting

[image]

You could follow this document for adding [authentication to bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample#configure-the-identity-provider-connection-and-register-it-with-the-bot)